# How to match regex with dollar amounts and phrases in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex

```
Pattern pa = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\$|hello|world|foo|blah blargh)\\b");
Matcher m = pa.matcher("$");
boolean b = m.matches();
System.out.println(b);
```

This prints out false, but I'm not sure why.

Why?

https://coderpad.io/GWFMKYQQ --> coderpad if it helps.

Comment: The `\b` anchor is failing because there are no word characters in your string.

Comment: You could try this: https://regex101.com/r/pG1aY8/1

Comment: Use `Pattern pa = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)(\\$|hello|world|foo|blah blargh)(?!\\w)")`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that `\b` word boundary is ambiguous: when it appears *after a word character* (i.e. a letter, digit or underscore), the next character must a non-word one or the end of string. When `\b` stands after a non-word character it requires a word character to appear right after it, also excluding the end of the string.

So, if your intent is to match `$` only if it is not enclosed with word characters, use *unambiguous* `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` lookarounds:

```
Pattern pa = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)(\\$|hello|world|foo|blah blargh)(?!\\w)")
```

`(?<!\w)` will fail the match if the `$` is preceded with a word character, and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead will fail the match if `$` is followed with a word character.

**NOTE**: If you add `(?U)` (or `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag), `\w` and `\b` will become Unicode aware (it might be important in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research on this, and it turns out, the `\b` metacharacter **does not like dollar signs.** You can match a dollar sign after a space by using the regular expression below:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)\\$")
```

And trimming out the preceding whitespace with another regular expression:

```
Pattern.compile("\\S+")
```

Alternatively, since this is Java, and not JavaScript's crap regex engine, you can just use this:

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s)\\$")
```

Comment: It has no problem with dollar signs. `\b` likes *word boundaries*, i.e. the beginning or end of a *word*. `$` is not a word. `$b` has 2 word boundaries (before and after the `b`), so you see, the `\b` did not shy away the `$`.